# LaTeXTools custom builder for feynmf/feynmp

Tags: compiling, feynmf, sublime-text, build-system, feynman

I'm using LaTeXTools with ST2, and I need to draw some Feynman diagrams. feynmf/feynmp both require additional commands to compile. Does anyone know the correct syntax for a custom builder that will incorporate this?

Comment: Please provide an MWE. What "additional commands" are you referring to?

Comment: What is an MWE?

Comment: It's a __Minimal Working Example__. See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that . It really helps others to figure out what your problem is. And therefore it makes it more likely that your question is going to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Just using the package

```
\usepackage{feynmf-auto}
```

might do the job, you just have to run pdflatex twice to get the reprocessed graphs.